# Scripts don't see ROS if executed by ProcessBuilder()

Tags: ros, bash, rosrun, java, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I want to execute a script with a `ProcessBuilder()`. My code is:

```
new ProcessBuilder().inheritIO().command("/bin/bash", "-c", "./deploy.sh").start();
```

In the bash script I have:

```
#!/bin/bash
rosrun my_package ardrone_test_1.py
```

It works if I run the bash script manually in the terminal, but if I do with the `ProcessBuilder` I got an error:

```
rosrun: command not found
```

The same if I run python scripts which uses ROS. There are errors that some package are not found, whereas it works fine if run via terminal.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/325808/scripts-don%27t-see-ros-if-executed-by-processbuilder()/) by [Cipek](https://answers.ros.org/users/42571/cipek/) on ROS Answers with karma: 5 on 2019-06-14

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You need to source setup.bash first in order for the environment to work. In your deploy.sh add a line like "source /your/ros_ws/devel/setup.bash" before you call rosrun

---

Originally posted by [davrsky](https://answers.ros.org/users/33130/davrsky/) with karma: 26 on 2019-06-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Cipek](https://answers.ros.org/users/42571/cipek/) on 2019-06-20**:
I have been looking for the solution really long and that worked! Thank you.